# {} in Python not calculating as expected

Tags: python

I am learning python through a book Learn Python the Hard Way 3.

I am doing exactly what the author is requiring but getting different values. Below is a summarized part of the problem. I am currently on the road so don't have the book but this is from memory since I tried it 100 times last night.

```
age = '35'
height = '74'
weight = '180'

total = {age} + {height} + {weight}

print(f"If I add my {age}, {height} and {weight}, I get {total}.")
```

The author says I should be getting 289. However, I keep getting 3574180. I have retyped, proofed it over and over and still getting the string of age, height and weight 3574180 versus the sum of all three 289. I am baffled and would appreciate any feedback. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Doesn't *3574180* look familiar?

Comment: Calculate `total` as sum of ints. I don't get why you wrapped variables inside `{}`. Should be `int(age)` for example.

Comment: I mean, I didn't wrap the variables inside {}. That was the author. Thanks for the response. I will try this when I am home again.

Comment: Unless you are using a recent beta version of Python which implements a new feature I'm not aware of, the above code *should not even work*. Wrapping a variable / value in braces (outside of a format string) will create a **`set`** with it as the sole item, and the operator `+` is not defined for `set`s.

Comment: My guess it that you remembered something about braces `{}` but forgot that it was just for use in string formatting.

Comment: You use string '35' and not integer 35 so you get string concatenation and not integer. I'm not aware of python but in other langage it's like this ;)

Answer (score 2):

You are adding strings, so your result is the concatenation of age, weight, and height. Instead, do:

```py
total = int(age) + int(height) + int(weight)
```

This will convert the values to `int`, which can be added together

Answer (score 0):

what is happening here buddy is that your input of age , height and weight is a string ''
so what happens at total is

```
total = '35' + '74' + '180'
```

they just getting combined together its not a calculation here

to calculate the string must be converted to an integer or float

```
total = int(age) + int(height) + int(weight)
```

this will perform mathematical calculation and your code will work correctly

Comment: so I can go two ways from here. Remove the ' around age = '35' or convert that variable into an integer int(age)? Is that accurate? I will try when I can doing it both ways. But what would be best practice in your experience? Should I do both as a learning habit? Just trying to avoid bad habits! Thank you.

Comment: Yes mate you can do both ways, beauty of python there is no one standard answer. In your case you probably better off with going by removing the ' ' marks.

Comment: But consider a scenario like : age = input('What is your age? ') , thats where you would ask the user to input their age and python interpretor will always return this as a string (because its a user input so its kinda of a default) , thats where you would use the int(age) to convert the user input from a string to an integer and do calculation on it

Answer (score 0):

After working through the logical errors I believe the correct program code is as follows. I have tested it a few times and it calculates the earnings accordingly.

```
barsInACase = 12
costPerCase = 8.00
costPerSingleBar = 1.00

#asks for the user to enter the number of bars they sold
sold = int (input ("How many candy bars did you sale? "))

#calculates the number of cases sold based off of the users input
casesSold = sold / barsInACase

#calculates the net earnings using the users input
netEarnings = (sold * costPerSingleBar) - (casesSold * costPerCase)

#displays the net earnings
print ("Your net earnings are $",
format (netEarnings, ',.2f'), ".", sep="")

#calculates the amount that the SGA gets
studentGovernmentAssociation = netEarnings * 0.10

#calculates the amount that the cheer team gets
cheerTeamsProceed = netEarnings - studentGovernmentAssociation

#displays the amount that the SGA gets
print ('The student government associations earnings are: $',
       format (studentGovernmentAssociation, ',.2f'), ".", sep="")

#displays the amount that the cheer team gets
print('The cheer teams earnings are: $',
      format (cheerTeamsProceed, ',.2f'), ".", sep="")

#displays a congratulatory message if the cheer team gets more than $500
if (cheerTeamsProceed >= 500):
    print ("Congratulations! You have raised $500 or more!")

#displays a sorry message if the cheer team gets less than $500
else:
    print ("Sorry! You did not meet your goal! ")
```